# Solving a limit of n+1

Tags: calculus

I was solving a problem on power series and was stuck on solving the following limit:

> $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \bigg|
>  \frac{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}} \bigg|$

The answer key in the textbook gave me the answer, which I did not fully understand.

> $\bigg|
>  \frac{\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} t^{\frac{1}{t}}}{\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}}} \bigg|$

How do I determine the limit above?

Thanks,

Comment: if $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x)$ exists and $\lim_\limits{x\to a} g(x)$ exists and not equal to $0,$ then $\lim_\limits{x\to a} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} =\frac { \lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x)}{\lim_\limits{x\to a} g(x)} $

Answer (score 2):

If we denote
$$ y_n = \frac{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$
Then:
$$ \ln y_n = \frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} - \frac{\ln n}{n} $$
We note that:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n} = 0 $$
(We can either recall that logarithmic functions have smaller order of growth than power functions, or use L'Hopital's Rule).

And so:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln y_n = 0 - 0 = 0 $$

By continuity of the exponential function:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = \exp \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln y_n \right) = \exp(0) = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

The limit of $n^{1/n}$ as $n \to \infty$ is $1$. This result can be found in most calculus books. For instance it appears in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* as Theorem 3.20(c).

From this, it follows that
$$ \frac{1}{1} =\frac{\lim\limits_{m + 1 \to \infty} (m + 1)^{1/(m + 1)}}{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n + 1)^{1/(n + 1)}}{n^{1/n}} $$
using the quotient rule for limits.

---

The rigorous proof for 3.20(c), given in Rudin's book is as follows. We let $x_n = n^{1/n} - 1$ then

$$ n = (1 + x_n)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}x_n^k \ge \binom{n}{2}x_n^2 = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}x_n^2. $$

We can remove the other terms because they are $\ge 0$ (since $x_n \ge 0$). Thus

$$ 0 \le x_n \le \sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}} \to 0 $$

as $n \to \infty$ using a previous result that $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$.

---

Another proof, using l'Hospital's rule is as follows. Note that $$n^{1/n} = \exp(\log(n^{1/n})) = \exp\left(\frac1n \log(n)\right). $$

Using the continuous function rule for limits, we have

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n} = \exp \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{n} \right)$$

and an application of l'Hospital's rule gives

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n} = \exp \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1/n}{1} \right) = \exp(0) = 1. $$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}&=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}}
\\
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot e^{\frac{\log(n+1)}{n(n+1)}}\to 1\cdot e^0=1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align} \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}} \right|
&=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left|(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right|}{\left|n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right|}  \\
&= \frac{\left|\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right|}{\left|\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right|}  \\
&= \frac{\left|\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} t^{\frac{1}{t}}\right|}{\left|\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right|}  \\
&=1
\end{align}$$